# Search for image on web using Google CustomsearchService

Tags: c#, google-image-search

I need a little bit help in this. The following code works flawlesly when I search the web as is but when I want to search for images

```
        const string apiKey = "xxxx";
        const string searchEngineId = "xxxx";
        const string query = "apple";
        var customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });
        var listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
        listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
        listRequest.Num = 1;
        //listRequest.Fields = "items(image(contextLink,thumbnailLink),link)";
        listRequest.SearchType = CseResource.ListRequest.SearchTypeEnum.Image;
        listRequest.Start = 1;

        var search = listRequest.Execute();

        foreach (var result in search.Items)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Title: {0}", result.Title));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Link: {0}", result.Link));
        }
```

`search.Items` results ing `null` when `SearchType` is `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

My bad sorry. I forgot to turn On image serch on the Google CSE page. And now it works fine.